# Side effect of Czech package?

Tags: packages, languages

Since I need to show a character in `Czech`, I use the following:

```
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
```

This makes everthing looks good including the Czech character, except for the following line showing unexpected result in the generated .pdf:

```
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
(skip)
\begin{appendices}
```

becomes like below instead of printing "APPENDICES":

```
P RÍLOHA A
```

Any solution idea is appreciated.

Comment: babel does not change the available characters, it changes the language elements such as section titles to the selected language (as well as setting up hyphenation for that language). If you just want a single Czech character no package should be needed.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina thanks for attention. I updated the original question to try to provide info as much as possible. Just assuming the issue I had was related to the package I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self response. Inspired by hint given by @David Carlisle, removing the usepackage phrase and adding the following line was enough for me.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

As I updated the original question, the issue occurred at the expressiong that is based on certain package. Thus I still don't know what the root cause is, nor whether the issue is associated with Czech package either.

Comment: Glad you got it working. As for your original comment, the main aim of babel is to translate the headings. I do not speak Czech, but google translate suggests that (apart from the space after the P) PRÍLOHA A would be a plausible translation of appendix A (google translates it as Annex A). The space is (presumably) a bug in the babel support?

Comment: Loading this package won't do anything regarding your problem, as the fixed words such as "Příloha" are defined independently from the input encoding. What you really need for Czech is `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. Load also `inputenc`, but this is for *inputting* the text, and it's not related to output.